# Scott Joplin "Solace", Sustained bass note with other notes in left hand

Tags: piano

The final section of Scott Joplin's "Solace" has notes in the left hand that look like this:

```
X: 1
M: 2/4
L: 1/16
K: Fmaj clef=bass
%%score (T B)
%
[V:T] C,,3G,[EC]2G,2
[V:B] C,,6G,2
```

Somehow you're supposed to hold down the dotted quarter while playing the other notes more two octaves away.

Should I not try to interpret this literally -- like an orchestral reduction, or what the composer would want played if you were recording for a piano roll or if you had an extra hand?  Implicit pedal markings?

Comment: @Aaron yes, pedal is one possible answer
My question is whether that is also the correct answer in this specific case

Comment: It is. That's why I voted it as a duplicate. Otherwise I or others would have left a case-specific answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is piano music.  A piano has a sustain pedal.  Depress it as you play the low C, release it with the final G.   Or, rather than releasing, 'change' pedal there, up and immediately down again.   As well as simply sustaining, the pedal adds resonance. Could be a good idea to keep that resonance going.

Comment: My ragtime band played this in the 70's, and the trombone just held the bass C.  Worked very well also.

Comment: Yes.  Piano players often have to 'fake' something which is easy and routine in instrumental scores.